# Upgrade pip install on Win10 box

Tags: pypi

I'm trying to upgrade pip install to 22.3. I keep getting this error, "default to user install because normal sit-packages is not writeable."
I'm at the cmd prompt in win10 trying to install.

This came about because I'm trying to install pypdf2 and this won't install to python that's in my environment path. So I'm stumped.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: did open the promt as an admin? if not then try it or write `--user` at the end of your command

Comment: @PakDragoon - thx for reply. I have opened cmd prompt as admin and tried both ways. I think my path and environment variables are pointing to different dirs. I get this error when running:C:\Users\araki>pip install pypi
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pypi
  Downloading pypi-2.1.tar.gz (997 bytes)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pypi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pypi
  Running setup.py install for pypi .done
Successfully installed pypi-2.1

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I just uninstalled conda & the vanilla python. I reinstalled just plain python for now.

I think originally I did not use venv properly and maybe my conda & vanilla pythons could have been mixed? Not sure. But my vanilla 3.11 is working now and I do some more work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the question with the answer that resolved the it. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install it with the --user flag, which will install it to your user directory instead of the system directory. This is not recommended, but it will work.

```bash
pip install --user pypdf2
```